# Instr() function with embedded quotation marks

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 strings and i am trying to find str1 in str2.

Str1= `""products":[]"`

str2= `"spConfig": {"attributes":{"149":{"id":"149","code":"pack_size","label":"Size","options":[{"id":"79","label":"SINGLE CIGAR","products":["680"]},{"id":"80","label":"PACK OF 3","products":[]"`

my

```
instr(1,str2,"'products':[]")
```

returns 0 and I am not sure why. Many thanks.

Comment: Why not use `Str1`?

Comment: you need to double up the quotes to get a quote in the string `str1 = """products"":[]"`

Comment: @Warcupine i think `Str1` is already correct assuming `"products":[]` is the string wanted. Edit: not sure why OP wrote it manually instead.

Comment: `""products":[]"` is not a valid string though.

Comment: @findwindow If you want the string <"products":[]> you need to use double quotes in place of single quotes. `"""products"":[]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround whatever your string is in quotations:

> MyStringNumber1 Becomes -> `"MyStringNumber1"`

You also need to replace existing quotation marks with double quotes so VBA knows to include a quotation mark there:

> My"String"Number1   Becomes -> `"My""String""Number1"`

Or going in the other direction:

> `Debug.print """My""StringNumber1"` will print "My"StringNumber1

> `Debug.print "My""""StringNumber""""1"` will print My""StringNumber""1

To answer you question, I believe this is what you're trying for here:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExampleSub()

Dim Str1 As String
Dim Str2 As String

Str1 = """products"":[]"
Str2 = """spConfig"": {""attributes"":{""149"":{""id"":""149"",""code"":""pack_size"",""label"":""Size"",""options"":[{""id"":""79"",""label"":""SINGLE CIGAR"",""products"":[""680""]},{""id"":""80"",""label"":""PACK OF 3"",""products"":[]"""

Debug.Print InStr(1, Str2, Str1)
    'Immediate Window Output = 176

End Sub
```

Please note I had to replace all your single quotes with double quotes.